# vb.net Report Viewer

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, reportviewer

I've got a report in vb.net 2010... It works fine, I've now added in some columns into the database and refersehed the datasources which the columns appear.

But when I go to build the code it reports that the fields don't exist within dataset1 which is really starting to annoy me now. I can't find where the dataset1 is to refresh the data.

Can somebody please advise?

Comment: I can't really understand what you're asking. When you said "refreshed the datasources", are you talking about refreshing the database itself? I know sometimes the client won't "know" of the database's new stuff if you don't. I've had that problem with stored procedures before.

Comment: Well on the report it says the field doesn't exist within the dataset..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252085.aspx

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.